# Dropdown Menu Not Working When Implementing with Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, drop-down-menu

I'm new to working with Django and am running into a problem implementing it into the static site that I've made.

Could you please advise as to why the dropdown menu is not working (not dropping down)? It was working fine when it was just the html/css files before django implementation.

Attached image shows the file/folder layout - please let me know if you need to see any of the additional files and I can post them. Am thinking I have some css in the wrong directory (?)   Image: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTucA.jpg)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="Test Site">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

        <title>Test Site</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test Site Web Application"/>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'themes/images/favicon.ico' %}">

        <!-- Google icon -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

        <!-- Propeller css -->
        <!-- build:[href] assets/css/ -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/propeller.min.css' %}">
        <!-- /build -->

        <!--Propeller date time picker css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css' %}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'components/datetimepicker/css/pmd-datetimepicker.css' %}" />

        <!-- Propeller theme css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'themes/css/propeller-theme.css' %}" />

        <!-- Propeller admin theme css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'themes/css/propeller-admin.css' %}" />
        </head>
        <body>

        <!--Start Nav bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top pmd-navbar pmd-z-depth">
            <!-- Placement Navbar -->
            <section class="row component-section">
                <!-- placement menu code and example -->
                <div class="col-md-12">            
                    <!-- placement menu example -->
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- User information -->
                        <div class="dropdown pmd-dropdown pmd-user-info pull-right">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-user dropdown-toggle media" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="material-icons md-light pmd-md">person</div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Logout</a></li>
                                {% else %}
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Login</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pmd-user-info pull-right">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-user dropdown-toggle media" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="material-icons md-light pmd-md">search</div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                <!-- section content start-->
                                <form id="validationForm" action="" method="post">
                                    <!-- here -->
                                    <div class="container-fluid full-width-container">
                                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
                                                    <label for="regular1" class="control-label">
                                                        Search...
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="regular1" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>       
                                </form>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="dropdown pmd-dropdown pmd-user-info pull-left">
                            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-custome">Test Site/a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="pmd-sidebar-overlay"></div> -->
                </div>
            </section><!-- Placements Navbar end -->   
        </nav>  <!--End Nav bar -->

        <!--content area start-->
        <div id="content" class="pmd-content inner-page">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <!-- content area end -->

        <!--footer start-->
        <footer class="admin-footer">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                <li>
                    <span class="pmd-card-subtitle-text">TestSite <span class="auto-update-year"></span>.</span>
            </li>
            <li class="pull-right for-support">
                    <a href="contact.html">
                    <div>
                          <h3 class="pmd-card-title-text">Contact Us</h3>
                        </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </footer>
        <!--footer end-->
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: See the resulting html.

Comment: I don't see anything? did you post/edit?